# Quickblox through UWP app on Raspberrry Pi 3

Tags: javascript, uwp, quickblox, raspberry-pi3

We are building video conferencing into our UWP app, running on Raspberry Pi 3 (ARM processor). In the [Quickblox UWP SDK documentation](https://quickblox.com/developers/QuickBlox_Developers), there is no "Video calling guide" like for the Android, JS and iOS SDKs. Is that a coincidence, or is it because there are not video capabilities in the UWP SDK?

An alternative is to use the Javascript SDK from Quickblox and making a UWP app on HTML/JS, but still unsure of whether it will run on an ARM processor. Is that an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Video calling function is implemented and fully supported on IOS/Android/Javascript. For UWP there is no ready-made solution for now.